# Writing a QGIS Processing Provider

Tags: qgis, development, qgis-processing

Due to limitations in the processing script framework (for example, inability to specify an optional field) I'm thinking of writing a Provider.

I found the example [ExampleAlgorithmProvider](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/exampleprovider) but no documentation.

Two questions:

- Are the interfaces used by the example provider considered stable and unlikely to change in any way that breaks compatibility?
- What is the recommended way to distribute/deploy a custom provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the break compatibilty part, I let the dev community answers.
For the second part, you can distribute your Qgis Processing Provider like a plugin (it's a plugin).

A good example is the LecoS plugin : https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LecoS/